# Is it possible to know when application starts in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to know is there any mechanism by which my C# code knows that application starts. For example when camera or music player starts then my app know each time that camera or other app has started.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot listen for when other applications start. You can use [Launchers and Choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769542%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to start the Camera from inside your own application, but you cannot listen on other applications.

Anyway, such a application would also be considered spyware.

Comment: then give me suggestion, i want to build an app which monitors battery usage by each application then plot it on graph. how can i do it then?

Comment: You can't. Only OEMs have permission to do that.

Comment: then if you have access to microsoft's officals tell them, ship this kind of app with wp 7 and thanks for your response.